# Running a shell script in Android from the Host

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have a Host development PC running Ubuntu and I am doing all the android development on it.From this PC I wanted to (adb) push some files(executables) to android filesystem (say /data/dir1) , cd into  it and run that executable.Using a shell script (shown below) I can do this from the PC upto to connecting the android device and doing adb shell but I can not run other commands after that .
e.g scripts

```
adb push <file1> /data/dir1/ 
adb shell
cd data/dir1
./file1
```

I  can run upto adb shell but not beyond that.How can I achieve the remaining two commands ( changing the directory to data/dir1 and running the ./file1) from the shell script running on the Host PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.first of all go the root by the command sudo -i

2. write the program

adb shell ls data/dir1

3.execute it -./file
by the above program you can move to the folder in the shell

Answer (score 7):

You

> don't need to enter into the adb shell

, change the path and more.

You can accomplish everything in a single command , like

```
adb push my_script_file.sh  /data/dir1/ 

adb shell sh data/dir1/my_script_file.sh
```

Comment: any comment on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746538/android-running-two-application-script-with-a-reboot-in-between-without-manual

Comment: Ar yeah! We need `sh` in front of the shell script. May I ask why we need `sh`?