# Running two application/script with a reboot in between without manual Intervention

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I have two c application running on android 
say helloWorld and helloHell . I need to run both but with a reboot in between.
I have adb pushed the applications to a folder in android file system and created two scripts :

```
helloworld.sh and helloHell.sh 

inside helloworld.sh : 
 ./helloworld
  reboot

inside helloHell.sh  : 
 ./helloHell
  reboot
```

I have written a shell script on the host PC like this :

```
hell-world.sh



1->adb shell sh helloWorld.sh
2->some calculated delay
3->adb shell sh helloHell.sh
```

But the problem with this is after running first script (1->) the command hangs(may be due to reboot inside the helloworld.sh) and I have to manually do CTRL+C , and then manually run the second script(2->) once the reboot is over.
I even tried killing after the first script execution(1->) by doing something like this

```
PID =$!
kill -9 $PID
```

but invain,

My aim is to run both the applications with a reboot in between with no user intervention in between.The problem here is after the reboot no new command after that will be executed and have to terminate it manually.

Comment: periodically check if your device is available, using `adb devices`. After the device becomes available again, wait for a while if you want & continue further commands.

Comment: the problem is  even before device becoming available after reboot.That is the terminal windows doenst returns to next line and remains in hang state until I Press CTRL+C which I wants to avoid.

Comment: This will help you for the `wait for a while` part in above comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091035/adb-receive-broadcast-boot-complete

Answer (score -1):

Remove `reboot` from script file & try this

```
adb shell sh helloWorld.sh
adb shell reboot
# add some delay here
adb shell sh helloHell.sh
```

Comment: if I put everything in a script as you said the prompt will never come after reboot and I have to manually do CTRL+C which I dont want.